# MS Access hyperlink--different depending on mode of entry?

Tags: string, ms-access, hyperlink

I have several tables with hyperlinks.  Sometimes those hyperlinks need to be updated (when, for instance, the files in the hyperlinks are moved).  Sometimes the updated hyperlinks need to be converted to strings for use in other applications.  An inconvenient thing that happens in both these cases is that if a link was entered or updated manually, the resultant string is the link duplicated twice with strange characters (../..) between duplicates.  This is problematic in many applications.  Advice?

Answer (score 0):

I have long recommended that people avoid hyperlinks in tables. If you must copy them, they are in the format:

```
display text#hyperlink#
```

You can create a query to pull the address:

```
 SELECT Table1.AHyperlink, 
        Mid([ahyperlink],InStr([ahyperlink],"#")+1) AS HAdr
 FROM Table1;
```

The above is just a rough suggestion and will have # on the end.